# How to create a list of alphabets to use with grid coordinates? (ie. a, b,...,z, aa, bb,...,zz, aaa,etc)

Tags: python

Pretty much as the title says. I can't seem to find a way to generate the letters. I need it because I am writing up some code for the game Battleship, so I'm going to use it to define a grid.

Comment: I thought Battleship used a grid with A-L along the top and 1-10 along the left side.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29)

Comment: I would advise defining your grid with numbers internally and only translate to a different notation for the purposes of input and output.  It'll make the game logic easier to write.

Comment: Yes but I'm required to meet the needs of the user, so the user can theoretically specify any valid grid size and I would have to make sure the labels are correct.

Comment: Well, you know that there are 26 letters in the alphabet. It's still better to use integers and convert to letters via modular arithmetic when you actually need to display them, not to mention easier.

Comment: @JDx, apparently it's been a while since you've been here, but you might want to accept some answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
import itertools
one_letter_items = list(string.lowercase)
two_letter_items = [''.join(x) for x in
    itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=2)]

items = one_letter_items + two_letter_items
```

or the more compact form:

```
items = list(string.lowercase) + [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=2)]
```

You can continue adding longer strings in the same way, by using another call to `itertools.product()` with increasing `repeat` values (though why you would need more than 702 columns for a game of Battleship, I don't know).

If you're not going to use *all* of the letters, you can make things more efficient using generators:

```
items = itertools.chain(string.lowercase, (''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=2)))
```

Comment: Clean and pythonic.  `string.lowercase` is so handy for things like this.  Not to mention itertools ;^)

Comment: I mean, if we really wanted to make it even nicer, we could use `itertools.chain()` instead of adding lists together, but meh. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully general solution using base-conversion. It's inspired by Steven Rumbalski's comment; use it to convert from number to letter designations. It doesn't generate `aa, ab..` and so on because it treats `a` as `0`. Not quite what you asked for in that sense, but I prefer this behavior; it uses a more consistent idiom.

```
>>> from string import lowercase
>>> def base_26_gen(x):
...     if x == 0: yield x
...     while x > 0:
...         yield x % 26
...         x //= 26
... 
>>> def base_26_chr(x):
...     return ''.join(lowercase[i] for i in reversed(list(base_26_gen(x))))
... 
>>> [base_26_chr(x) for x in range(100)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 
 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'be', 
 'bf', 'bg', 'bh', 'bi', 'bj', 'bk', 'bl', 'bm', 'bn', 'bo', 'bp', 'bq', 'br', 
 'bs', 'bt', 'bu', 'bv', 'bw', 'bx', 'by', 'bz', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd', 'ce', 
 'cf', 'cg', 'ch', 'ci', 'cj', 'ck', 'cl', 'cm', 'cn', 'co', 'cp', 'cq', 'cr', 
 'cs', 'ct', 'cu', 'cv', 'cw', 'cx', 'cy', 'cz', 'da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd', 'de', 
 'df', 'dg', 'dh', 'di', 'dj', 'dk', 'dl', 'dm', 'dn', 'do', 'dp', 'dq', 'dr', 
 'ds', 'dt', 'du', 'dv']
```

Going backwards is easier:

```
>>> def b26_chr_to_b10(x):
...     return sum((ord(c) - 97) * 26 ** i for i, c in enumerate(reversed(x)))
... 
>>> b26_chr_to_b10('ab')
1
>>> b26_chr_to_b10('ba')
26
```

Answer (score 0):

use `chr()` and `ord()`:

```
abc = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
```

Comment: Er, why? `list(string.lowercase)` is far simpler for that task.

Comment: `list(string.lowercase)` is another way to give the `['a', 'b', ... , 'z']` value you have in `abc`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question anyway--at least, not as the title would imply.  It seems to ask for continuation into double, triple, etc. "digits".

Answer (score 0):

Similar to amber's answer; except this produces one giant list with all one, two, three letter combinations in order (and easily extendable to longer combinations by increasing 4 in `range(1,4)`).

```
import string
import itertools
ordered_abc_list = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,
                          map(lambda N:[''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=N)],
                              range(1,4)
                              )
                          )
```

Or if you prefer creating a generator rather than a list:

```
ordered_generator = (''.join(s) for s in
                        itertools.chain(*map(lambda N:itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=N), 
                                             range(1,4)
                                             )
                                        )
                     )
```

Which can be used like

```
for x in ordered_generator:
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear from your question, when you run out of single letters do you want to get all combinations of two letters (`aa, ab, ac, ..., zy, zz`) or do you want to just repeat the same letter twice (`aa, bb, cc, ..., yy, zz`)?

The other answers will give you the former (all of the combinations), just in case you are actually looking for the latter, here is a solution:

```
from itertools import islice, count
import string

width = 60
columns = list(islice((c*n for n in count(1) for c in string.lowercase), width))

>>> print columns
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj', 'kk', 'll', 'mm', 'nn', 'oo', 'pp', 'qq', 'rr', 'ss', 'tt', 'uu', 'vv', 'ww', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh']
```

This will work for any arbitrary number that you use for `width`, 60 is just an example.  The generator `(c*n for n in count(1) for c in string.lowercase)` will infinitely generate unique strings of increasing length, and [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is used to only take `width` elements.